# Why am I forced to use MAX() and how can i rewrite code?

Tags: sql, max

I have a table with columns:

```
EGAIT1  EGACAM      EGVONO
2440     -18242,39  1416341
6995      18242,39  1416341
2995      18242,39  1416341
6995     -18242,39  1416341
2995      18242,39  1416341
2995     -18242,39  1416341
```

I want the Query to see if the accounting rows containing accounts 2995 or 6995 add upp to zero, and if not, I want the question to return the number of account that does not add up to zero and the sum of the difference in amount.

My Query is the following:

```
SELECT 
MAX(FGLEDG.EGAIT1),
SUM(FGLEDG.EGACAM)

FROM SEUHABOB.MVXADTA001.FGLEDG FGLEDG

WHERE (FGLEDG.EGAIT1 IN ('2995','6995'))
AND (FGLEDG.EGVONO=1416341)

GROUP BY FGLEDG.EGVONO
HAVING SUM(FGLEDG.EGACAM) <> 0
```

The problem is that since I am forced to use `MAX(FGLEDG.EGAIT1)` the question retuns the incorrect account number.

Is there some way to "split" the WHERE condition so it makes one execution per account, and only `returns MAX(FGLEDG.EGAIT1)` for each execution?

(I have tried to only use one account at the time, and then it returns nothing for 6995, which is correct, and 2995 18242,39 for 2995, also correct.)

My expected result is:

```
EGAIT1    EGACAM      
2440     -18242,39  
6995      18242,39
```

Comment: Can you please show your expected result?

Comment: EGVONO where this field?

Comment: Please update the question. Also, you are grouping by `EGVONO`,not the columns you showed. Is there a typo in the query?

Comment: I have corrected the question... sorry.

My expected result is:

EGAIT1  EGACAM
2995       18242,39

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FGLEDG.EGAIT1, SUM(FGLEDG.EGACAM)
FROM SEUHABOB.MVXADTA001.FGLEDG FGLEDG
WHERE (FGLEDG.EGAIT1 IN ('2995','6995'))
GROUP BY FGLEDG.EGAIT1
HAVING SUM(FGLEDG.EGACAM) != 0
```

The mere problem is that grouping has to be done for EGAIT1, to use this without MAX.

---

*(After altered question)*

It could be that you want the following *combined* grouping:

```
SELECT FGLEDG.EGVONO, FGLEDG.EGAIT1, SUM(FGLEDG.EGACAM)
FROM SEUHABOB.MVXADTA001.FGLEDG FGLEDG
WHERE FGLEDG.EGAIT1 IN ('2995','6995')
GROUP BY FGLEDG.EGVONO, FGLEDG.EGAIT1
HAVING SUM(FGLEDG.EGACAM) != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just interested in those two accounts 2995 and 6995 you could do the following:

```
SELECT FGLEDG.EGAIT1, SUM(FGLEDG.EGACAM), FGLEDG.EGVONO

FROM SEUHABOB.MVXADTA001.FGLEDG FGLEDG

WHERE (FGLEDG.EGAIT1 in ('2995', '6995')
AND FGLEDG.EGVONO=1416341)

GROUP BY FGLEDG.EGVONO, FGLEDG.EGAIT1
HAVING SUM(FGLEDG.EGACAM) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to output data only when the two specified accounts are not zero.  IF so, then you can use window/analytic functions to add the values for these "accounts" in a subquery:

```
SELECT EGVONO, EGAIT1, cnt, sum_EGACAM
FROM (SELECT EGVONO, EGAIT1, COUNT(*) as cnt, SUM(EGACAM) as sum_EGACAM,
             SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN F.EGAIT1 IN ('2995', '6995') THEN EGACAM END)) OVER (PARTITION BY EGVONO) as sum_2995_6995
      FROM SEUHABOB.MVXADTA001.FGLEDG F
      GROUP BY FGLEDG.EGVONO, EGAIT1
     ) x
WHERE sum_2995_6995 = 0
```

Comment: I'm a beginner at SQL, this seems a little advanced. But I will try this, I have been wondering about how to do a subquery. Thanks!